# Is my proof correct: Show that there is infinite prime numbers $8k + 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

First of all, note that all odd and prime divisors of $n^4 + 1$ have the form $8k + 1$.
Suppose that there are just finite prime numbers of form $8k + 1$.
Construct the number $a = (2p_1\ldots p_n)^4 + 1$, where $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^n$are all primes of form $8k + 1$.
This number is odd, and has at least one prime divisor $q$.
Then $q$ has the form $8l + 1$. But then $q = p_j$ for some $j$. But it is not possible since $q$ divides $a$ and $q$ divides $(2p_1\ldots p_n)^4$, i.e, $q$ divides 1.

Comment: Why do all odd prime divisors of $n^4+1$ have the form $8k+1$?

Comment: Let $q$ an odd prime divisor of $n^4 + 1$. Then $n^4 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod q.$
Then $n^8 \equiv 1 \pmod q$. Then the order of $n$ in $Z_q$ is $8$. But $8$ divides $q-1$. Then $q \equiv 1\pmod 8.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks good.  The only change I would suggest would be to include more detail about why all odd prime divisors of $n^4+1$ are of the form $8k+1$, since that's not immediately obvious.